# How to enable button upon dropdown item selection in js?

Tags: javascript, html, list, for-loop

This snippet displays two select elements, and a submit button. Initially, button is disabled.

Desired behavior: enable submit button when both elements have second option (`complete`) selected. If either one of the elements has first option (`received`) selected, disable the button.

Current behavior: button is enabled/disabled regardless of the first select element. Meaning: If I select option `received` in the first dropdown, and option `complete` in the second, button will be enabled, instead of disabled.

```js
function enableButton() {
  var all_statuses = document.body.querySelectorAll(".selected > .form-control");
  var option_two = "complete";
  for (var i = 0; i < all_statuses.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " This will work")
    if (all_statuses[i].value == option_two) {
      document.getElementById("btn_completed").disabled = false;
    } else document.getElementById("btn_completed").disabled = true;
  }
}

$(document).ready(enableButton);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="selected">
    <select class="form-control" id="select_one" onchange="enableButton()">
      <option value="received">received</option>
      <option value="complete">complete</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="select_two" onchange="enableButton()">
      <option value="received">received</option>
      <option value="complete">complete</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<button id="btn_completed">Completed</button>
```

So, the question is: How to enable the button if all select elements have option `complete` selected, or how to disable the button if at least one select element has option different than `complete` selected?

Comment: This is not a Django issue. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62017599/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor to create a [mcve] with HTML, CSS and JavaScript ONLY

Comment: Also NEVER call anything in a form `="submit"` if you ever want to submit a form using script. Also disabling a submit button will stop a submission if you test the existence of the button on the server

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but are you setting same button enabled and disabled multiple times? Maybe you should use break; once disabled?

Comment: Removed confusing parts. I believe the issue is probably the wrong way of looping through the list. As I said, I get the button functionality either for the first item in the list, or the last. @Antti Yes. I have a list of items in the form, each item has a select element with two values. What I need is for button to be enabled, only if second option is selected for all items. If the second option is not selected for even one item, the button should be disabled again.

Comment: The select field you have shown contains two options with the values `item_one` and `item_two`, but you are comparing the value of the select field (which results from the selected option), to `complete`? Is there something missing from your description, like that these option values get set/changed dynamically by something else, or …?

Comment: Thanks CBroe, made the adjustment.

Comment: 1. getting console errors in the snippet I made (definition of btnComplete is missing) 2. There is no onload attribute on a form 3. Never call anything submit 4. Whatever you called submit is missing from your code. 5 Why ID on the options? 6. Why not a normal ID, # needs to be escaped when trying to use it in a selector

Comment: I have adjusted the snippet, removed what is not necessary for minimal reproducible example. What do you think? Thanks

Comment: Set initial to enabled and if some of those values are not correct then disable it and use break; otherwise it continues the loop and the last item will decide is it enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="selected">
    <select class="form-control" id="select_one" onchange="enableButton()">
      <option value="received">received</option>
      <option value="complete">complete</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="select_two" onchange="enableButton()">
      <option value="received">received</option>
      <option value="complete">complete</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<button id="btn_completed" disabled>Completed</button>

</body>
<script>
function enableButton() {
debugger;
  var all_statuses = document.body.querySelectorAll(".selected > .form-control");
  var option_two = "complete";

  var isdisabled = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < all_statuses.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " This will work")
    if (all_statuses[i].value != option_two) {
      isdisabled = true;
      break;
    } 
  }

  if(isdisabled) {
    document.getElementById("btn_completed").disabled = true;
  }
  else {
document.getElementById("btn_completed").disabled = false;
    } 

}

$(document).ready(enableButton);
</script>
</html>
```